# Manual submit in jquery skipping validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, validation

I want to edit a number but if I use a keypress: enter to submit my form, it skips validation of numbers 1-20 and submits to my route.

```
<form action="/editrank>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
<input type="number" min="1" max = "20" name = "rank" value = "1"> 
</form>
```

jquery:

```
  $("input").keypress(function(event){
            if(event.which === 13){
                   $(this).closest("form").submit();
            }
        });
```

I can add a submit button and it will validate if I click the button but not when I press ENTER.

Comment: what kind of validation is there for the field

Comment: @ArunPJohny the min and maxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the form is valid like

```js
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    if ($form[0].checkValidity()) {
      $form.submit();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/editrank>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="20" name="rank" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: this worked very well but I've added a second input into the form and now when I press ENTER nothing happens, I tried using !$form[1].checkValidity() but i guess that's not the correct way

Comment: @CXNAJ : than select input based on their `ID` or `class`

Comment: @YoYo I have a forloop creating multiple inputs from my database and want validation for "this" instead of for all the them at once